# Mark as duplicate for an identical question that was answered outside Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Sometimes the exact same question is asked verbatim in two different places, for example:
On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956675/how-can-i-calculate-the-angles-between-a-polygons-vertices) and in [MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1585914-how-can-i-calculate-the-angles-between-a-polygons-vertices).

The author has accepted the answer to the latter case, and I wanted to discuss whether this can be marked somehow as a way to close the question. The close as duplicate only works within Stack Overflow...
Any views?

Comment: Add a CW wiki pointing to that other answer. Do make sure to check wether or not that other site allows copying their content and under what conditions.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are "_repositories of knowledge_"; whether the question (even an exact copy) has been answered elsewhere is kind of irrelevant, _if_ it's a high quality and on-topic question that belongs here.

Answer (score 11):

This wouldn't, fundamentally, be any different to a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/7872) so pretty much all the reasons that they're a bad idea would also apply to closing a question on a Stack Exchange site as a duplicate of a question answered on a non-Stack Exchange site.

Referencing off-site resources in an answer that support the answer, or provide additional context or information that's broader/deeper than the question being answered is great. Relying on an off-site resource to provide the answer to a question.. that's brittle for many reasons and shouldn't be considered for the network.